# Smart animate problem in icon of basic slider

Tags: user-interface, figma, figma-api

I have made a small animation with 2 pages.
I want to make a loading slider.
I have a coffee icon and a loading bar(rectangle with curved edges).
When you preview this you will see only the rectangle animation but when you click on restart prototype, the icon will appear and the loading slider animation will work perfectly.

I want this slider to work perfectly without using the restart prototype button. I want both, the icon and the rectangle to work perfectly together in one go without restart prototype.

I am creating a very basic slider just for the beginning and I really need your help.

https://www.figma.com/file/ibZee11nEFq7nwhZoScQGX/1234?type=design&node-id=1%3A873&mode=design&t=vzvjV5gptCzEYIQ5-1

I tried changing the delay time for icon but doesn't work.